# Terminating file upload to NodeJS backend causes Apache 502 Gateway Error

Tags: node.js, apache, file-upload

I've got an Apache webserver proxying some requests to a NodeJS backend. When the user uploads a invalid file, my server terminates the request with an error message. While this works correctly when calling the NodeJS backend directly, a 502 Bad Gateway error ("The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
") is given when proxied through Apache.

The NodeJS termination (req = request, res = response)

```
            req.pause()
            res.statusCode = 400
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.end("Invalid Request: " + e.message);
            req.destroy(["Invalid Request: " + e.message])
```

I'd like to immediately end the upload (to save time & bandwidth), and send an error message to the client, so simply pausing the request doesn't work for me - it leaves the client hanging. Not setting "Connection: close" or destroying the socket causes upload to continue, even after res.end is called with the error message.

I am seeing an "http error before end of send, stop sending" error in Apache, so it's pretty clear that Apache is treating this as a backend server fault, rather than a legitimate error message to be returned to the client. How do I fix this? I've done quite a bit of searching, but haven't found a clear answer.

The current proxy code (not much):

```
ProxyPass /node http://127.0.0.1:3000/node
```

More code can be provided upon request.